# How to import .fbx MODEL into Unity Project?

Tags: unity, fbx

I created new Project in Unity. I downloaded .fbx file from internet, it looks like as give in image.
How can I import .fbx into Unity Project. I am beginner and this is my first Unity Project.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I voted this down because it doesn't show any attempt to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: I agree with your downvote, Thanks for mentioning it. Next time I will try my best before posting question @Byte56

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply drag the .fbx file to the project assets folder.
[image: GuidePicture]

Comment: Note that this will sometimes fail (it does in my case and with consistency), but copying the file and then browsing into the directory and then pasting it there is exactly the same thing as doing this. Unity will just detect the file and import it as usual.